# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException en cambio de caracteres

Tags: java

Pequeña porción de código que itera sobre una cadena, con setCharAt sustituye la primera letra de cada palabra y provoca excepción.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String mensaje = "hola mundo";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < mensaje.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = mensaje.charAt(i);

        sb.append(ch);

        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            ch = mensaje.charAt(i + 1);

            char letra = Character.toUpperCase(mensaje.charAt(ch));
            sb.setCharAt(ch, letra);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Si tienes una excepción, es que el código compila y se ha ejecutado. Una excepción es un error durante la ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando el valor de un carácter como índice:

```
ch = mensaje.charAt(i + 1);
char letra = Character.toUpperCase(mensaje.charAt(ch));
sb.setCharAt(ch, letra);
```

Compila porque un char es equivalente a un "unsigned" short (2 bytes) y el *casting* se hace automáticamente sin warnings, pero el carácter y la posición del mismo son dos cosas distintas.